# React native keep getting Text string must be rendered within <Text>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs

Can someone tell me why I keep getting this error:

> Text string must be rendered within a  component

I've taken out portions of the API key.

**Here is my code**:-

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
        `https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=11300ce692510973c&ids&interval=5m,30d&convert=GBP&per-page=100&page=1`
      ).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
          const ndata = data;
          const test = data.map((element) => element);
          this.setState({ new: test }); })}
  render() {
  const test = this.state.new.map((e)=>{return(<SvgUri width="10%" height="10%" source={{uri:e.logo_url}}/>)})
    return (
<View>{test}</View>
    )
  }     
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap `test` in a `Text` component if it ended up having a type `string`. In react native, you can only put text within a `Text` component

```
<View>
  <Text>{test}</Text>
<View>
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this like this.

{
`test.map(logo => logo)`
   }

Because here test

`const test = this.state.new.map((e)=>{return(<SvgUri width="10%" height="10%" source={{uri:e.logo_url}}/>)})`;

returns a array of svg

Comment: orry abit confused how would i implement that?

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
        `https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=11300ce692510973c&ids&interval=5m,30d&convert=GBP&per-page=100&page=1`
      ).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
          const ndata = data;
          const test = data.map((element) => element);
          this.setState({ new: test }); })}
  render() {
  const test = this.state.new.map((e)=>{return(<SvgUri width="10%" height="10%" source={{uri:e.logo_url}}/>)})
    return (
`{ test.map(logo => logo) }`

    )
  }     
  } Try using this code

Comment: this doesnt work maybe the code formatting?